# In Akka 2.0, can I restart an actor on a new remote node from a supervisor?

Tags: akka, fault-tolerance

Assuming a supervisor that is supervising a remote actor. If the remote actor dies because its entire Akka node has been terminated, is it possible to resurrect the actor on a new Akka node, keeping all existing ActorRefs to it alive?